# Parsing a POJO to JSON using JAX-RS and not using any speific implemnation code

Tags: jersey, cxf, jax-rs

I was looking at internals of jersey, on how it converts a simple POJO to Json. Jersey has an interface Providers, which will provide list of contextResolvers given the class and mediaType. once we get the contextResolver, we can get the Context and Marshaller from it, which can used to get the json string, like show below.

lets assume we want to serialize the Pojo "obj". the code will look like follows

```
Providers ps = ...
ContextResolver<JAXBContext> resolver = ps.getContextResolver(obj.getClass(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
JAXBContext ctx = resolver.getContext(obj.getClass());
ctx.createMarshaller().marshal(obj, writer);
```

By above way we can convery any POJO which has a valid context resolver to json. but the question is how do we get the handler for Providers.

PS: i have not compiled this code, but from what i can see from source this is what jersey does. On why i am doing all this stuff, so that we can convert a object to JSON directly with JAX-RS apis. instead of using any implementation code.

Answer (score 1):

In a JAX-RS resource clas, use the @Context annotation to tell Jersey to inject the producers:

```
@Context Producers producers;
```

Answer (score 0):

So your question is : "how to find providers" ?

You have to write code to find classes in the classpath which are Annotated with @Provider.

Comment: Yes. But then jersey which would have already done this. So is there a way to access this Providers (here by Providers i mean javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers).

Comment: Yes, jersey may have. Scanning the classpath like i am suggesting will be a one time operation; done during your app's bootstrap. Btw, have you considered using [http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/] GSon? I have not used it, but the project description seemed interesting.